# what is a good way to efficiently store a list of c++ objects from different classes using Flatbuffers?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I have a list of c++ objects derived from different classes. I would like to use Flatbuffers to persist/restore them.

An obvious way to do this is with a union, but i do not want to waste bytes or use a vector of pointers to a superclass (assuming this is an option in Flatbuffers).

Another way is to store the concatenated bytes of all the objects and a separate map from the object index to the byte offset and class type.. but perhaps there is a better way.

Another way would be to use internal links in the objects which allow them to refer to each other. This would allow efficient storage of arbitrary data structures. This is currently my preferred route, but i am not sure if it is possible - and it may not be the best option. Perhaps if i overrode the pack/unpack mechanism it might be possible to place byte offsets into the link fields. Usage of full reflection would be ok.

any assistance would be appreciated!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Mr van Oortmerssen, creator of Flatbuffers, it is possible to create a union of tables, where each table corresponds to an object class, then reference that union in each object in the list.

Example at https://github.com/batwicket/flatbuffers_list_test.